# How to get tracking link in BigCommerce GET shipments API

Tags: bigcommerce

I am fetching shipment details from bigCommerce get shipment API but getting "" empty value for tracking_link.
How to get tracking_link value in API?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking the same question here: [How ShipStation is generating order shipment tracking URL using tracking_number and carrier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790668/how-shipstation-is-generating-order-shipment-tracking-url-using-tracking-number/67812186#67812186)

Answer if so,
0

This could be happening if you're omitting both tracking_carrier and shipping_method. If these are not included, there will be no tracking link.

A tracking link is always generated if either (not mutually exclusively) shipping_provider or tracking_carrier is supplied alongside a tracking number and as long as the value for either carrier code is valid according to our supported list.

If you're asking this due to your integration with Shipstation -- It is recommended for you to reach out to Shipstation about this, to see if they're seeing unexpected results via the API. If so, let me know so I can provide the next steps to this. Thank you!