# How ShipStation is generating order shipment tracking URL using tracking_number and carrier?

Tags: bigcommerce

ShipStation is showing only shipment tracking_number on UI it is not displaying tracking URL and not returning this tracking URL in API response as well.

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening if you're omitting both tracking_carrier and shipping_method. If these are not included, there will be no tracking link.

A tracking link is always generated if either (not mutually exclusively) shipping_provider or tracking_carrier is supplied alongside a tracking number and as long as the value for either carrier code is valid according to our supported list.

It is recommended for you to reach out to Shipstation about this to verify if Shipstation is seeing unexpected results via the API. If that is happening, please let me know so I can provide the next steps to this. Thank you!